# use .effect() function on just created class which is tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a tr and appending it to tbody.and giving a class to tr too.

```
var temp = '<tr class="newTr"><td>blah</td></tr>'
$("tbody").append(temp);
```

now I want to use

```
$(".newTr").effect("highlight", {}, 1500);
```

But its not working.
Can any body tell what is the problem

Comment: How are you appending it to the body?

Comment: it has to be called after the element is added to the dom

Comment: there is a type in the script `'<tr class="newTr"></tr>'`

Comment: Checked for any error in the console?

Comment: no error in the console

Comment: the tr should have atleast one `td`

Comment: I think you have to call the file http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sA3mW/1/

Comment: also you need jquery ui also

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jsFiddle for you where everything works fine. Also i added a remove class trNew in order not to highlight all the added tr elements.

[Check out the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PyZys/1/)

Your example does not work because of numerous JS syntax errors and because your  element has no content in it so it can not be visible.

```
var temp = '<tr class="newTr"></tr>'
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work, so adjust it to your needs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var temp = "<tr class='newTr'><td>Bla</td></tr>";
   $("tbody").append(temp);
   $(".newTr").toggle("highlight");
});
```

I think you made a mistake with double quotes and single quotes.

Edit: changed the highlight code

Comment: The quotes are fine both ways.

Comment: As long as the quotes are nested correctly, it doesn't matter if the singles are inside the doubles or vice versa.

Comment: He edited the first post where he had faults in his quotes, he fixed them now